# No instala el apk en Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Al darle en run app en android studio para probar la app en mi dispositivo físico no termina de instalar el apk, no sube la barra de carga y el spinner no para de girar. Antes si lo hacia, ¿Alguien sabe a que puede ser debido? Ya que no he tocado ni cambiado nada, además que la app si se visualiza en el dispositivo, aunque en Android studio pase lo comentado anteriormente. Gracias.

Comment: a cual spinner te refieres? comentas que no carga la aplicación!

Comment: Me refiero a un pequeño spinner de carga que aparece en la parte de abajo en Android studio junto al texto de instalando apk, ese spinner gira y la barra de carga no

Comment: en la consola muestra algun mensaje ? has esperado a que termine tratar de instalar?

Comment: has intentado ejecutar tu aplicación en otro teléfono? o has intentado ejecutar otra aplicación?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes activado Instant run? A mi a veces me da problemas y al desactivarlo suele funcionar todo. Puedes comprobarlo en File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y que tengo que activar porque no veo por ninguna parte Instant run

Comment: He editado la respuesta, puedes ver donde está y que, a la derecha, aparece "Enable Instant Run" marcado. Prueba a desmarcarlo.

Comment: Gracias lo tengo igual y sigo con el mismo Problema

Comment: Quizá no me he explicado bien, quiero decir que a mí me da problemas cuanto está como en la imagen. Si lo quito suele funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

comentas que si muestra la aplicación pero la barra de progreso no sube.

Puede ser que el .apk generado lo suba ya que no detecto cambio en el código.
si deshabilitaste la opción `Instant Run` , `File` >`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment.`

reconstruye el proyecto mediante: `Build` > `Clean project` > `Build Project`

esto obligara a subir una nueva versión del .apk

---

Algo pudiera esta fallando probablemente con el cable de tu dispositivo pero pudiera ser el ADB, puedes probar reiniciando Android Studio, o directamente en este `Tools` > `Android` > `Android Device Monitor`. Selecciona la opción que muestro en la imagen para resetear el ADB (Android Debug Bridge):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso ya lo he probado, creo que el fallo debe de estar en el dispositivo

Comment: Reiniciar el ADB o tu AS.